Synchronizing polygon changes between layers using QGIS
I'm working with two distinct SpatiaLite layers, each with specific fields (they are not duplicates of each other).
While working on HABITATS_POLY, I aim to update ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY based on field values.
1] I intend to insert records into ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY when the field "HAB_ZH" equals 'H.' Below is the trigger I've implemented:
CREATE TRIGGER I_rapat_zh_poly 
AFTER UPDATE OF CODE_ZH ON HABITATS_POLY
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY (geom, Visibilite, CRITERE, pkuid, LABEL_HAB) 
    SELECT NEW.geom, 'Oui', 'Critère de végétation', NEW.ogc_fid, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO 
    WHERE NEW.CODE_ZH = 'H.' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY WHERE pkuid = NEW.ogc_fid); END;

2] When the geometry of a polygon is updated on HABITATS_POLY, I aim to synchronize the shape of the corresponding polygon in ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY. Unfortunately, I haven't found a direct method to modify geometry in SQLite. Instead, I'm exploring ways to add newly created polygons and delete outdated ones in ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY.
Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?
I found Keep geometries in different layers in sync while editing but the solution is proposed on PostgreSQL. I'm using SQLite.

You can use an Update statement in a Trigger similar to your 1.
Here's an example as an SQL statement that you can adapt with a trigger and your specifics.
I have two layers poly1 and zhpoly with common a common pkuid field, both are Spatialite layers
I have created different geometries for each. This Update statement will update the zhpoly to match the ploy1 geometries where the pkuid is the same if the poly1.name is 'A'.
update zhpoly
 set geometry=(select geometry from poly1 where zhpoly.pkuid=poly1.pkuid and poly1.name='A') 
 where (select geometry from poly1 where zhpoly.pkuid=poly1.pkuid and poly1.name='A') is not null 


All different geometries in zhpoly:

After the SQL statement is made, geometries are updated to match poly1 geometries where name='A', unchanged otherwise:


@Kasper’s answer helped me to figure out what was going wrong.
Here are the 2 triggers:
    CREATE TRIGGER I_rapat_zh_poly 
AFTER UPDATE OF CODE_ZH ON HABITATS_POLY 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY (geom, Visibilite, CRITERE, pkuid, LABEL_HAB, ogc, NOM_ZH) 
    SELECT NEW.geom, 'Oui', 'Critère de végétation', NEW.id, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.ogc_fid, NEW.ASSO_ZH
    WHERE NEW.CODE_ZH = 'H.' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY WHERE pkuid = NEW.id); 

    DELETE FROM ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY 
    WHERE pkuid = NEW.id AND NEW.CODE_ZH <> 'H.'; 
END;

CREATE TRIGGER updt_geom
AFTER UPDATE OF geom ON HABITATS_POLY 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 

    UPDATE ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY
    SET geom = hp.geom
    FROM (
        SELECT h.id AS h_id, h.geom
        FROM HABITATS_POLY h
        WHERE h.CODE_ZH = 'H.' AND h.geom IS NOT NULL
    ) AS hp
    WHERE ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY.pkuid = hp.h_id;   

    DELETE FROM ZONES_HUMIDES_POLY 
    WHERE pkuid = NEW.id AND NEW.CODE_ZH <> 'H.';
    
END;

I had to adjust my project and other triggers. For now, it is working well.
